# Rules of thumb for divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Given a number presented in decimal form $n=\sum_{k=0} d_k10^k$ there are some nice thumb rules to decide whether it is divisible with a prime number 
$p\in\{7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$.

For each of this numbers there is a number 
$a_p$ such that $p|n\iff p|(a_p\cdot d_0+\sum_{k=0} d_{k+1}10^k)$.

$a_7=-2,\;a_{11}=-1,\;a_{13}=4,\;a_{17}=-5,\;a_{19}=2,\;a_{23}=7,\;a_{29}=3$

E.g. $\;19\cdot 17=323$ and $32+2\cdot 3=38=2\cdot 19$ and $32-5\cdot 3=17$.

Is there a number $a_{31}$ that works the same way? Or $a_p,\;p\ge37$?

Comment: By [this general divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242)

$$ \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{p\mid 10\,b+a \iff p\mid b+c\,a}\ \ {\rm for}\ \  c\equiv {10}^{-1}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!p},\ \ 2,5\nmid p\qquad $$

e.g. for $\,p=29\,$ we have $\bmod 29\!:\ c\equiv \dfrac{1}{10}\equiv \dfrac{3}{30}\equiv \dfrac{3}1\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. For all primes $p$ other than $2$ and $5$ the rule $a_p=1/10$ works. The arithmetic is to be done in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ (or, modulo $p$):

- With $p=7$ we have $10=3$, so $a_7=1/10=1/3=-2$.
- With $p=11$ we have $10=-1$, so $a_{11}=1/(-1)=-1$.
- With $p=31$ we have $10\cdot(-3)=-30=1$, so $a_{31}=1/10=-3$.

The reason is that when $10a_p\equiv1\pmod p$ we have
$$
n=\sum_{k\ge0}d_k10^k\equiv 10\left(d_0a_p+\sum_{k>0} d_k10^{k-1}\right)\pmod p.
$$
Therefore $n$ is divisible by $p$ if and only if $10(d_0a_p+\sum_{k>0}d_k10^{k-1})$ is.
Because $\gcd(10,p)=1$ cancelling that factor $10$ won't change divisibility by $p$, and we get that $n$ is divisible by $p$ if and only if the number
$$
a_pd_0+\sum_{k>0}d_k10^{k-1}=a_pd_0+\lfloor\frac n{10}\rfloor
$$
is divisible by $p$.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be the same way at all. The product $a_p\cdot d_0$ should be an integer to be added to $[n/10]$.

Comment: @Lehs: It is the same! Trying to make it clearer... done editing.

Comment: Beauty! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Yes, that's what I call an answer!

Comment: Sorry about being finicky with the details initially. Glad to see you like this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yesterday I asked about the case of 7 and you mentioned me this 
generalization question at first I didn't understand it , but now  after contemplation this answer is very great I understand it...  In my opinion  ,  mathematics is really interesting very much.

Comment: Hope you enjoy the never-ending journey of learning more math @Mahmoudalbahar!